The tags [development], [programming], [source] and [code]
The development tag is widely used but lacks a description. The programming tag has been made a synonym of it. There is also the source tag that has the following description:

Specifically refers to the source code from which applications may be compiled or the process of said compilation. Do not use to request a source of information or to determine the source from which Bitcoins originate, etc.

and the tag code that is only used in one place. To me it seems obvious that "source" and "code" are synonyms and should be renamed "source-code" to make it clearer. I'm not so sure about the other ones though. There is a merge request for "code" -> "development" that I'm not sure is right. Any suggestions of a description for the "development" tag?
Also, have a look at this older question and give your input there:
Is there a way to resolve the ‘client’ and ‘developement’ tags ambiguities?

I'm all for renaming to [tag:source-code] and merging with [tag:code]. I agree that [tag:code]->[tag:development] is probably not right. Let's get a little more input first but I'd feel comfortable supporting the premise here. Make sure to throw something in the tag wiki for whatever you end up merging to prevent future confusion.

I have changed source to source-code. Both code and source are now synonyms of source-code.

I agree that code and source should be merged into source-code.
As for development, I believe it is different from code, as it might involve non-coding development, for example creating ASICs or the like. I already created a stub description of the tag as follows:
"Related to creation and ongoing work for different existing and future Bitcoin-related projects and source code."

I think that all of them are meta tags. They are all broadly defined, mean different things to different people and hardly ever used as the sole tag for questions (outside of questions that were shot down anyway).
[source-code] could become meaningful, if it referred specifically to the source code of one program such as for example bitcoind, however, then it should rather be used as [bitcoind-source-code].
[development] could be meaningful if it were used to tag questions that scrutinize the development process of the bitcoin protocol and standard client, however, we already have tags for those. As it is, it is being slapped on any question that deals with development of any bitcoin related software and as such does not narrow down the content of a question by itself without other tags.
Similar things can be said [programming], [value], [currencies], [alternates], [services], [software], [statistics], [exchange-rate], [accounts], [logging], [monitoring], [graphs] ...
